# Speed up search function for PDFs

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pdf

This function takes a file path to a PDF file, and a search string(s). It spits out a count of the number of times the string(s) shows in the PDF. Any ideas how I can make it faster?

It can be tested with any PDF (not password protected.)

I frequently use this to scan a list of words in a large number of PDFs and it is slow!

```
import os
import fitz # using PyMuPDF
import string
def count_of_string_in_pdf_file_advanced_alt(next_pdfs_path: str, search_string: str) -> int:    
    """
    count the number of times a string is in a PDF file. Case insensitive.
            Parameters:
                    next_pdfs_path (str): file path to a PDF file
                    search_string (str): string to look for/count in PDF file
            Returns:
                    count (int): a count of the number of occurrences
    """
    count = 0
    flag = True
    search_string = str(search_string.lower().strip()) 
    if os.path.isfile(next_pdfs_path):      # check file is a real file/filepath
        try:
            text = ''
            with fitz.open(next_pdfs_path) as doc:
                for page in doc:
                    text += page.get_text()
            while flag:
                text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) # remove puncuation
                words = text.lower().split() # cleanup and split the text into list of words
                words = sorted(words)
                if search_string in words:
                    count = words.count(search_string)
                    break
                else:
                    flag = False
                # return count
        except (RuntimeError, IOError):
            pass
    return count
```

I profiled it using a single string and this 74 page PDF https://thedocs.worldbank.org/en/doc/79bb914488308f1e75744fccc4e12cb3-0290032021/world-bank-notes-on-debarred-firms-and-individuals-pdf

```
                 7998 function calls (7989 primitive calls) in 0.182 seconds

   Ordered by: call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      453    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
      444    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:621(__getitem__)
      312    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
      300    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'own' of 'SwigPyObject' objects}
      296    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:3003(CheckParent)
      296    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:3047(<lambda>)
      296    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.abs}
      151    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
      149    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:5755(__contains__)
      149    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:4408(page_count)
      149    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method fitz._fitz.Document_page_count}
      148    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 weakref.py:164(__setitem__)
      148    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:347(__new__)
      148    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFF295E13D0}
      148    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _weakref.proxy}
      148    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.id}
      148    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.round}
       84    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
       77    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:252(popitem)
       77    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 weakref.py:243(values)
       77    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'popitem' of 'dict' objects}
       77    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:17(__init__)
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:27(__exit__)
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:121(_commit_removals)
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:21(__enter__)
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen _collections_abc>:966(clear)
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'values' of 'dict' objects}
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'set' objects}
       75    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:289(update)
       75    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:104(__init__)
       75    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 fitz.py:7227(_reset_annot_refs)
       75    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 fitz.py:5778(__getitem__)
       75    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 fitz.py:7240(_erase)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:352(__init__)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:152(__contains__)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:497(__init__)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 fitz.py:4146(load_page)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:434(util_make_rect)
       74    0.001    0.000    0.135    0.002 utils.py:753(get_text)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.126    0.002 fitz.py:6009(get_textpage)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:926(__init__)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:5898(<lambda>)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:636(__len__)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 fitz.py:3046(JM_TUPLE3)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 fitz.py:6892(cropbox)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.125    0.002 fitz.py:6002(_get_textpage)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:6972(rotation)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:5839(_forget_page)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.000 fitz.py:9002(extractText)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:8909(<lambda>)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 fitz.py:7253(__del__)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.000 fitz.py:8993(_extractText)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 fitz.py:9086(__del__)
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method fitz._fitz.util_make_rect}
       74    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method fitz._fitz.Document_load_page}
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method fitz._fitz.delete_Page}
       74    0.129    0.002    0.129    0.002 {built-in method fitz._fitz.Page__get_textpage}
```

Some things I have tried

```
# I tested using join rather than concatenating but found it to be slower.
        # for page in doc:
        #     text += page.get_text()
        text = ' '.join(page.get_text() for page in doc)
```

Comment: (When trying to speed up something, please invest at least 5 seconds of profile.)(A trailing codereview code block needs to be followed by a newline.)

Comment: If you dig into the fitz module's `get_text()` function, you actually have options of getting a `dict` of the full output, which contains massive amounts of extra data. Not useful for you in this case, but reading the PDF is non-trivially expensive due to the format.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## where did the time go?

Thank you for including measurements.

Ordering the profiler output by call count is uninteresting.
What you care about is time spent,
and the output makes it pretty clear that nearly all
the delay happens in `get_text()`.
Everything else is just noise.

> Any ideas how I can make it faster?

If you're not happy with the current PDF text extractor,
then choose another.
It might come with convenient python bindings.
Or it might just produce plain text on stdout,
which a parent python process can consume and grep through.

Consider writing a `foo.txt` cache file
each time you parse some original `foo.pdf` document.
Then you will never have to parse a document twice,
and elapsed time on subsequent runs boils down
to time for grep'ing a text file.
This is a time vs. space tradeoff,
where spending disk blocks saves us CPU seconds.

## design of API

> frequently use this to scan a list of words

The current Public API accepts a single word and reports a count.
If your list of N words starts with "apple", "banana",
the call sequence would be

```
pdf = "/some/where/World-Bank-Notes-on-Debarred-Firms-and-Individuals.pdf"
a = count_of_string_in_pdf_file_advanced_alt(pdf, "apple")
b = count_of_string_in_pdf_file_advanced_alt(pdf, "banana")
...
```

You just did N expensive `get_text` operations
followed by a trivial cost grep-and-count operation.

Rather than a single word at a time, prefer to pass in
a container of words:

```
>>> from collections import Counter 
>>> cnt = Counter(dict(apple=0, banana=0))
>>> cnt
Counter({'apple': 0, 'banana': 0})
```

That way for each .PDF file you can `get_text` just once,
and report all the desired word counts as a single return value.

An alternate approach would be to pass in a regex:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(apple|banana)\b', re.I)
```

## long identifiers

```
def count_of_string_in_pdf_file_advanced_alt(next_pdfs_path, ...
```

These would probably benefit from being shortened a little.
If you still have more things to say about them,
the very nice existing docstring is a good place to do that.

## short identifier

```
            while flag:
```

That is too vague.

Yes, we can see it is of type `bool`.
But we don't know what it *means*.

It should be called `not_found`.

Or better, invert its meaning and rephrase,
since humans do better with positive identifiers.

```
            while not found:
```

It's unclear why we're even looping here at all.
The `if` will either `break` or change the flag.
Both of those actions cause the loop body's search
to happen exactly once.
Maybe this is leftover debug from when you
were exploring other ways of looping over pages?

## ETAF rather than LBYL

```
    if os.path.isfile(next_pdfs_path):      # check file is a real file/filepath
```

It's unclear why this check is needed.
If `fitz.open()` raises, it raises, no big deal.
And then either caller would see the exception bubble up the stack,
or caller would get a zero count, however you prefer to handle that.

Prefer
[Path()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use)
over `str` when putting pathname parameters in a function signature.

BTW the `text.translate()` is lovely, it runs very fast on the inside.
You have an opportunity to call `str.maketrans()` just once when
this module is `import`ed, and then keep re-using that
translation table, but that would be a very tiny savings
in the scheme of things.

Rather than **deleting** punctuation, you might prefer
to **substitute** such characters with SPACE.
My concern is that text like `"spin-weave"`
is being turned into the single word `"spinweave"`,
where likely `"spin weave"` would be preferable.

## unneeded action

```
                words = sorted(words)
```

This looks like a setup for calling
[groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
to obtain counts of *every* word in the document.
But then we go on to do something else.
Maybe it is leftover debug?

This is a relatively inexpensive operation,
but there's no need to do it
so we may as well drop it.

---

This codebase achieves many of its design goals.
Apparently its future development will mostly be
about choosing and integrating with faster PDF libraries.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance
tasks on this code.

Comment: "Consider writing a foo.txt cache file" how did I not think of doing that before now!

Comment: "Rather than a single word at a time, prefer to pass in a container of words:" yes I had considered doing this. Will give it a try.

Comment: For others, ETAF="Easier To Ask Forgiveness (rather than permission)"-> just run it, handle exceptions later, LBYL="Look Before You Leap" -> check pre-conditions first so we don't need to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

So I have taken onboard most of what was suggested and have moved towards pushing a list into the function. I have cleaned up the function, and am now using `collections.counter` which seems to be blisteringly fast when working with a large list but slower when just a single string.

testing

```
# Generate 1 million short strings

from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
chars = ascii_lowercase + digits
lst = [''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(5)) for _ in range(1000000)]

# function (yes still with the verbose name)

import os
import fitz
import string
from collections import Counter
def count_of_string_in_pdf_file_advanced_alt2(next_pdfs_path: str, search_list: list) -> int:    
    """
    count the number of times a string is in a PDF file. Case insensitive.
            Parameters:
                    next_pdfs_path (str): file path to a PDF file
                    search_list (list): list of strings to look for/count in PDF file
            Returns:
                    count (dict): a count of the number of occurrences of each string
    """
    search_list = [str(word.lower().strip()) for word in search_list]
    try:
        text = ''
        with fitz.open(next_pdfs_path) as doc:      # using PyMuPDF
            for page in doc:
                text += page.get_text()

        text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) # remove puncuation
        words = text.lower().split() # cleanup and split the text into list of words
        word_count = Counter(words)
        # make new dict keeping only the required strings
        word_count = {k: word_count[k] for k in search_list}
    except (RuntimeError, IOError):
        pass
    return word_count
```

Profile

```
import cProfile
import pstats
cProfile.run("count_of_string_in_pdf_file_advanced_alt(file_path, lst)", 'profile_results')
stats = pstats.Stats('profile_results')
stats.sort_stats('time').print_stats()

output with 1 million strings:-
3002833 function calls (3002829 primitive calls) in 1.442 seconds

output with 1 string
2800 function calls (2798 primitive calls) in 0.410 seconds
```

So with counting a single string it is slower than using `count`, but it scales very well!